# What's wrong with my d3 zoom in and zoom

Tags: d3.js, zooming, drag

I integrate d3's zoom in and out in  bipartite. 
When I zoom in(graph becomes bigger) and drag, it works fine.
But when I zoom out(graph becomes smaller) and drag, the graph jump away, I do not know where is the problem, can anyone help me? thanks.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/5ms1304v/)

```
 drawSvg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom)).append('g');

 function zoom() {
            drawSvg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

Find the problem, I need to change to

```
 drawSvg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom));
```

The limit scaleExtent([1, 3]) must 1, if it is 0.1, the view is smaller, and hard to do.

Comment: Please answer your own question if you found the fix.

Comment: yes, I found the problem, but actually, I have not yet find the best solution about setting scaleExtent(0.1,3). Maybe the problem is in the translation. Actually when I set 1, it is ok, because where to put is what I translate.